# Can't remove UILabel from UINavigationController.view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uilabel

I'm adding a tiny marker under my UINavigationController title so the user will know that the title is tappable.  You can see in the code below how I add this label to the navigation bar.

```
    _labelCalendarMenuArrow               = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2 - 5, 30, 10, 26)];
    _labelCalendarMenuArrow.text          = @" ̬";
    _labelCalendarMenuArrow.font          = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:30];
    _labelCalendarMenuArrow.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _labelCalendarMenuArrow.textColor     = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:_labelCalendarMenuArrow];
```

The problem is that I'm unable to remove this UILabel from the navigationController.view when leaving this screen. In the code below you can see how I try a few methods for hiding or removing this UILabel, but none of them work... The UILabel will stay in the NavigationController until I go to a different stack of views and come back. Any advice?

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [_labelCalendarMenuArrow removeFromSuperview];
    _labelCalendarMenuArrow = nil;
    _labelCalendarMenuArrow.alpha = 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW - the @" ̬" string I'm using as my label is kinda weird, and shows up weird... it should be between the quotations and not under the right quotation mark. ... ... maybe that has something to do with it...

Comment: Just tested... no, that has nothing to do with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be to use HIDDEN property

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
_labelCalendarMenuArrow.hidden=YES;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do here is fairly horrific, adding a view within a parent navigation controller's view is against all sense.

Please read apple's human interface guidlines as there is a better solution to signifying that the title is clickable in there. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/

If you still insist on adding a label underneath the navigation bar's title label you should implement a titleView for the navigation item. Within that view you will have to include your own title label to replace the original and then your signifier label underneath.

Comment: Yeah... I'm seeing the apple example and I'm not referring to a back button  or some default navigation concept.

The navigation title (titleView) in my navigationBar is a UIButton, which when tapped provides a selector to the user to select some options about the view. The navigation title itself needs to be clickable, and I cannot use color to indicate this.

But you did give me the idea of trying to add the UILabel as a subview of the titleView instead of the navigationController.view.